# In linux, wx.PopupWindow don't get any mouse event when it popup from wx.Dialog?

Tags: python, linux, wxpython, wxwidgets

Hi, everyone.

I have a little python GUI program based on wxPython 2.8.x.
It create a wx.Dialog widget and show the dialog by calling ShowModal().
At some situation, the wx.Dialog will show a wx.PopupWindow with a wx.ListCtrl locate inside.
The wx.PopupWindow appears correctly, but trouble comes.
wx.ListCtrl, and its parent widget, wx.PopupWindow, couldn't receive any mouse event,
this cause wx.ListCtrl and wx.PopupWindow have no response while user generate any mouse action.

If wx.Dialog is opened by calling Show(),
the above situation won't happen, wx.PopupWindow and wx.ListCtrl work correctly.

However, the above situation won't happen in windows version of wxPython 2.8.x even if we show wx.Dialog by calling ShowModal(),
it happen in linux only.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Here is my source code.
It may be too long but is easy enough to test the above situation (just copy and paste).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import wx



class TestPopupWindow(wx.PopupWindow): # modify here to change different Widget
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestPopupWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.SetSize((200, 200))

        self.testButton = wx.Button(self, label='Test')

        self.testButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.__onEvtButton, self.testButton)

        self.Show()

    def __onEvtButton(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        print 'PopupWindow: test button pushed!'
        self.Hide()


class TestDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetAutoLayout(True)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Fit(panel)
        sizer.SetSizeHints(panel)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        for i in xrange(2):
            ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
            sizer.Add(ctrl, 0, wx.ADJUST_MINSIZE|wx.EXPAND, 0)
        for i in xrange(2):
            ctrl = wx.ComboBox(panel)
            sizer.Add(ctrl, 0, wx.ADJUST_MINSIZE|wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.openPopupWindowButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Open PopupWindow')
        sizer.Add(self.openPopupWindowButton, 0, 0, 0)

        standardDialogButtonSizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
        self.standardDialogButtonSizerOK = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_OK)
        standardDialogButtonSizer.AddButton(self.standardDialogButtonSizerOK)
        self.standardDialogButtonSizerCancel = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        standardDialogButtonSizer.AddButton(self.standardDialogButtonSizerCancel)
        standardDialogButtonSizer.Realize()
        sizer.Add(standardDialogButtonSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        panel.Layout()

        # event binding
        self.openPopupWindowButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.__onEvtButtonOpenPopupWindow, self.openPopupWindowButton)

        self.popupWindow = None

    # event handler
    def __onEvtButtonOpenPopupWindow(self, event):
        event.Skip()

        if self.popupWindow is not None:
            self.popupWindow.Close()
        self.popupWindow = TestPopupWindow(self)



class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetAutoLayout(True)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Fit(panel)
        sizer.SetSizeHints(panel)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.openButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Open Dialog')
        sizer.Add(self.openButton, 0, 0, 0)

        self.openPopupWindowButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Open PopupWindow')
        sizer.Add(self.openPopupWindowButton, 0, 0, 0)

        panel.Layout()

        # event binding
        self.openButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.__onEvtButtonOpen, self.openButton)
        self.openPopupWindowButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.__onEvtButtonOpenPopupWindow, self.openPopupWindowButton)

        self.Show()

        self.popupWindow = None

    # event handler
    def __onEvtButtonOpenPopupWindow(self, event):
        event.Skip()

        if self.popupWindow is not None:
            self.popupWindow.Close()
        self.popupWindow = TestPopupWindow(self)

    def __onEvtButtonOpen(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        dialog = TestDialog(self, title='TestDialog')
        result = dialog.ShowModal()
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'OK!'
        else:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'Cancel!'



def main(argv=sys.argv[:]):
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = TestFrame(None, title='TestFrame', style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    app.MainLoop()
    return 0



if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Maybe you can add some code so people can try it out and see if it's specific to your system or not? You could also try asking this on the wxPython mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a PopupWindow, just show a second wx.Dialog. Or open a frame. PopupWindows can be kind of weird with complex widgets like the ListCtrl.

Comment: I have tried to use wx.Dialog and wx.Frame instead of wx.PopupWindow, but any window generated from wx.Dialog - started by calling ShowModal() - have no reaction, either. Is this an issue of wxPython or wxWidget for Linux?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't have a Linux box handy though. Could you cross-post to the wxPython mailing list? They could tell you for sure.